# Woocommerce B2B plugin or not necesario?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning,I al having a bit of trouble on finding the right approach for my business.

I have a wordpress + woocommerce site and my idea is to include the local stores on my site,but I dont want to manually upload the productos myself,I want them to have a account so they can create products,delete,control stock etc.

I found this B2B for woocommerce but not sure if It is what i need.

Could not find information on the web.
https://woocommerce.com/products/b2b-for-woocommerce/#

Comment: I think you're looking for a multi-vendor plugin like [WooCoomerce Product Vendors](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/) or [Dokan Multivendor](https://wedevs.com/dokan/)

Comment: Thanks @MosheGross I think the Woocommere Product Vendors might work!